# How to change index from primary key to another unique column?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

Here is the domain:

```
public class Citation
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string CitationNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime CitationDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

and the Fluent API:

```
ToTable("Citations");
HasKey(c => c.Id);

Property(c => c.Id)
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

Property(c => c.CitationNumber)
    .HasMaxLength(8)
    .IsRequired();

Property(c => c.CitationDate)
    .IsRequired();

Property(c => c.CitationAmount)
    .HasColumnType("Money")
    .IsRequired();
```

By default, an index is added upon the Guid field `Id`. To improve the performance, I would like to move the index unto `CitationNumber`, which is also a unique value field.

So the SQL Script should be like:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Citations
DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Citations]
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Citations ADD CONSTRAINT
    [PK_dbo.Citations] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (Id)

ALTER TABLE dbo.Citations ADD CONSTRAINT
IX_Citations_CitationNumber UNIQUE CLUSTERED (CitationNumber DESC)
```

I can add index on `CitationNumber`:

```
var indexAttr = new IndexAttribute("IX_Citations_CitationNumber")
    {
    IsClustered = true,
    IsUnique = true,
    Order = 1
    };

Property(c => c.CitationNumber)
    .HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(indexAttr))
```

But how can I remove the constraint on `Id`? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that, even in sql. Check the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189039.aspx).

> Creating a primary key automatically creates a corresponding unique,
>   clustered or nonclustered index.

What you could do is adding Index to another column, but you can't prevent EF creating an index on primary key column.

Here is how to add another index either using fluent api or attribute.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TheEntity>()
    .Property(e => e.TheProperty)
    .HasColumnAnnotation("IndexName", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute { IsUnique = true })));
```

or

```
[Index("IndexName", IsUnique = true)]
public int TheProperty { get; set; }
```

PS: But you can drop the Index later using sql query.

Answer (score 0):

For EF 7 it has been made easy. You can use the following option with the haskey option.

```
ForSqlServerIsClustered(false);
```

we can use it like

```
supplierItemEntity.HasKey(supplierItem => supplierItem.SupplierItemId).ForSqlServerIsClustered(false);

 supplierItemEntity.HasIndex(s => new { s.ItemId }).ForSqlServerIsClustered(true).HasName("IX_SupplierItem_ItemId");
```

[image]